# jwplayer7 sending erroneously & astronimically high playback position for Windows10 Edge14 users

Tags: html, flash, jwplayer, microsoft-edge

Occasionally jwplayer v7.9.1 sends back an erroneously high playback position in response to API call jwplayer().on('time’).  We are streaming mp4 files.  Files (audio only) that shouldn’t go any longer than three or four minutes report back with a time between 148204903 - 148205134 seconds.  We know in at least some of these instances users stopped playing the file before it was complete.

This only occurs on computers that report back using Windows 10 Edge 14 when we have the primary engine set to HTML5.

When we switch the primary engine to be Flash, this does not occur.  We’ve a temporary work around in place forcing any computer reporting as using Windows and Edge or IE to use Flash. This is obviously less than ideal.

Has anyone else encountered this?  We would like to get back to using HTML5 for our Edge users.